# Modal issue with html button updated by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, modal-dialog

I am using the following javascript code to update my HTML.

```
document.querySelector(".long-copy").innerHTML = "Once, there was a boy who became bored when he watched over the village sheep <a class=\"word-button\">grazing</a> on the hillside.";
```

This updates my HTML DOM (this one) dynamically.

```
<div>
<p class="long-copy"></p>
</div>;
```

Now, in my code - the word "grazing" is a  tag. When someone clicks on this "grazing" button, a modal window should open. BUT this is not working as when I run this javascript code, I get an error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". Please help.

```
const btn1OpenModal = document.querySelector(".word-button");
btn1OpenModal.addEventListener("click", openModal);
const openModal = function () {
  modal.classList.remove("hidden");
  overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
};
```

CSS added >>

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.word-modal-one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 56%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 6rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3rem 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: auto;
}

.word-modal-one::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: *"the word "grazing" is a button."* <-- No, it's an anchor (`<a>`), not a button (`<button>` or `<input type="button">`).

Comment: You'll have to add the relevant CSS for us to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I have edited the anchor tag (mistakenly wrote button as was testing with button). Also added CSS for modal window.

Comment: You also need to add all the other relevant code, like the `.word-button` element. Also, your opening `div` tag is incorrectly set to be a closing `div`.

Comment: Maybe the js code runs before the DOM has finished loading, and therefore it's `null`. If this is the error, you'll need to add an event listener to DOMContentLoaded, and *then* add the event listener to your button. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event ... If that's not your problem then it's an error in your selector.

Comment: Thanks Besto, I suspect the same that it is due to js code running before DOM. Trying to figure out a solution. Alternately, doing another window ref opening instead of modal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead change your `<a>` tag HTML to this:

```
var myHTML = "text text more text <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='openModal()'>My a element</a> more text text more text";
function openModal() {
    //Open that modal
}
```

I added the `javascript:void(0)` because without that, some browsers like to use the `<a>` tag to redirect, because it does signify a link, and that void stops the link from executing a redirect to the same page and lets you carry on with your JS on the same page

The reason why your `addEventListener` fails is because the script looks for an element that doesn't exist yet, and so you can bypass that by attaching the event listener yourself onto the element

Comment: Thanks, tried that too, but facing another error in this case. Modal window is always open, so I think js code is running before DOM opening and the button is always onclick.